# Can not send email by smtp using G Suit account.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, gmail

This question might be flagged as a duplicate But it is not. Because the code sends email successfully  when using normal gmail account that ends with **@gmail.com**. The problem only happens when using G suit accounts that are custom and ends with **@yourdomainname.com**.

I am using this code to send email. My account has two-step verification so I created an app password for verification and use it to send email.

```
using (var mm = new MailMessage(PrivateSettings.SenderEmail, message.Destination))
        {
            mm.Subject = message.Subject;
            mm.Body = message.Body;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            var networkCred = new NetworkCredential(PrivateSettings.SenderEmail, PrivateSettings.EmailPassword);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = networkCred;                
            smtp.Port = 587;                
            smtp.Send(mm);       
        }
```

**The above code sends email successfully  when I use my normal gmail account** which is se.natnael.zeleke@gmail.com.

But when I use one of my G Suit account , **connect@tatarri.com** , to send email it fails and shows this error message.

[image]

So my question is; is their additional configuration that should be done for G suit gmail accounts.

Additional Info.

I configured both email accounts to use app password. connect@tatarri.com is also registered as admin in my G suit account.

Both email accounts have their IMAP enabled in settings.

I bought tatarri.com domain name from namecheap.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your from address Gmail? so are you always having a gmail address as the from?

Comment: @BugFinder my from address only works when it is ***@gmail.com but fails to send email when my from address is one of my gsuit account, like ***@yourdomainname.com.

Comment: are your mails coming from the registered IP? if so why would you not be using the g suite relay?

Comment: @BugFinder my website is deployed on azure and I am trying to send confirmation email when users sign up.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Tells the SMTP client to use the default credentials of the currently logged in user. This is what you would use for a client application.

In your case, you want to specify credentials other than the current user's, so set it to `false`:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Comment: the code works fine the problem only happens when i use a different "from account". When using a normal gmail account like ***@gmail.com it works  but it fails when using G suit account like ***@yourdomainname.com.